# Fundamental matrix rank

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Is there any way one can prove that $\text{rank}\big(F+F^{T}\big)=3$? where F is a fundamental matrix. If you have any idea, do let me know.

I am trying to solve this problem.

[image]

I am just trying to understand the first part.

Comment: Some references with solutions: [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision - Epipolar Geometry and the Fundamental Matrix](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf) and [ECE 661 - Epipolar Geometry and the Fundamental Matrix](https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/computervision/ECE661Folder/Lecture21.pdf) (Backup - [ECE 661 - Epipolar Geometry and the Fundamental Matrix](https://docdro.id/UxIlTNL)).

Answer (score 5):

This is not a proof, but maybe an intuition why this conjecture can be true for the points in general position. From the properties of rank we know that:
$$
\mathrm{rank}(F) = \mathrm{rank}(F^\top) = 2.
$$
Hence:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{rank}(F+ F^\top) &\leq \mathrm{rank}(F)+\mathrm{rank}(F^\top)\leq 4.
\end{align}
$$
Because $(F+F^\top)\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, $\mathrm{rank}(F+ F^\top)\leq 3$. To have any rank deficiency here (e.g. $\mathrm{rank}(F+ F^\top)< 3$), we should have an additional rank constraint on $F$, which we donot seem to have. The only additional constraint is that $F$ has 7 degrees of freedom and that $\det(F)=0$. These non-linear constraints are not sufficient to reduce the rank.

Comment: I guess this is what they meant when they asked to convince ourselves. I don't know what else to show.

Comment: I really don't understand how this is an answer. This is the symmetric part of the Fundamental Matrix and by geometry can be shown to have rank 3 in the general case.

Comment: So as I said, it's not a proof. It's barely an intuition as to why no reduction would exist to reduce $F+F^\top$ from rank-3 to rank-2. Hence, we'd $\textit{convince ourselves}$ that the resulting rank is 3. If you have a stronger argument, I would be happy to see and learn from it. But merely citing references in the literature is not sufficient.

Comment: @Royi The citations you gave don't have anything regarding this problem in hand

Comment: Have you looked at the chapter which deals with the symmetric part of the matrix?

Comment: @Royi I think they do contain relevant information. However, it is only mentions that 'In general it has rank 3.'. I cannot see a principled proof there. If you are familiar with one, would you mind typing it down here?

Comment: Well, if you follow other properties about the epi polar lines I think you can generate. I didn't post the links as solutions (If there was a direct solution I'd post a screen shot as an answer). I just think the whole picture is there.

Comment: Yes, I thought in this direction a bit, but wasn't fruitful. I would appreciate seeing a solution here. Other than that the arguments do not take me very far then what I posted.